# Implement show/hide functionality using javascript in rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Actually, I want to execute javascript code into my rails application.

I created new file that is custom.js in "app/assets/javascripts".

custom.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div#test").hide();
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#test").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

I also added, //= require custom in application.js file but still the code doesn't hide at the very beginning.

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require nicetitle
//= require custom
```

index.html.erb

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-formed" style="float: right;" >Search</a>

                <div id="sample" class="<%= @xvaziris_data.present? ? 'hidden' : '' %>">

                    <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, method: 'get', class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                    <p>
                        <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", class: "form-control-search" %>
                            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                        </p>
                        <% end %><br>

                        <% if @xvaziris.empty? %>

                        <center><p><em>No results found for.</em></p></center>              

                        <% end %>

                    </div>
```

general.scss

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The above custom.js code, when I place in index.html.erb under javascript script tag it works fine. But I don't want to repeat myself in every other controllers/index as the rails is following DRY principle that is DONOT REPEAT YOURSELF.

search.js

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
        $("div#sample").hide();

    //    | === HERE
    $("a.toggle-formed").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#sample").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your custom.js is available in your page when you put in application.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  custom.js files is under "app/assets/javascripts" and it is a separate file.

Comment: yes but its must be enclose in `<script>` tag

Comment: i dont think you need to `//= require custom` adding custom.js into javascripts/ is sufficient enough. i tested this myself and it works fine in my build.

Comment: Have u tried to restart server after adding it

Comment: Marv is right. When you add custom.js to the application it is included in the asset pipeline. This is because the application.js has //= require_tree . directive.

Comment: Thanks, but my application.js file doesnot contain //= require_tree . directive, and I have other file with require nicetitle it works fine but why not custom.js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding the div on document ready. You could just use `display: none;` with css. Then when your document loads `fadeToggle()` would still work with it.

You should also consider using

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
```

because of turbolinks. Sometimes there are cases where turbolinks will change a page without loading it and the document on ready won't be called.

Comment: Excellent! It works and what if want to implement to the search as I don't want to hide when I searched for something but I would like to let it open for few seconds or when I trigger close it must close.Hope you understand the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to [@Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158594/4207394):

So when you need to implement for the search you may do it like this:

Add a class `hidden` in your css in the class write:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

So when the page loads check if the search data exists then don't add class `hidden` or else add it. Example:

```
<div id="test" class="<%= search_data.present? ? 'hidden' : '' %>">
```

So this will display it when the search data exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am getting this error   undefined local variable or method `search_data' for #<#<Class:0x00000009852f10>:0x00000009240dc0>

Comment: The `search_data` name was just an example, please replace it with the instance variable in which you are having the data from your controller.

Comment: Thanks. I add search.js for the reference. Does it needs any modification? Again it toggles back to hide when I click the search...

Comment: See initially the search would be hidden if you add `hidden` class to it. Now when the user searches something you will have some result for him. So on the view check that if it is present or not, if it is then don't add the `hidden` class to it. Or else add it. I have given the same example above.

Comment: Make this: `class="<%= @xvaziris_data.present? ? 'hidden' : '' %>"` to `class="<%= @xvaziris.present? ? 'hidden' : '' %>"` and try

Comment: After I changed, my search toggle stopped functioning now, as when it did as before it functioned that is with @xvaziris_data.